# How to trigger didSelectItemAtIndexPath at select center cell once the scroll end in ios swift?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uicollectionview, carousel

Here **UPCarouselFlowLayout** is used for carousel scroll. As of now, user must tap a cell in order to trigger collection view didSelectItemAtIndexPath. Is there a way to select the center cell once the scrolling ended automatically?

here is the code i used to carousel:

```
 let layout = UPCarouselFlowLayout()
    layout.itemSize = CGSize(width: 211, height: 75)
    layout.scrollDirection = .horizontal
    layout.spacingMode = UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode.fixed(spacing: 10)
    layout.spacingMode = UPCarouselFlowLayoutSpacingMode.overlap(visibleOffset: 65)
    carCollection.collectionViewLayout = layout
```

here the code used for collection view:

```
     func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {


    return carCategory.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! carCollectionViewCell

    cell.carName.text = carCategory[indexPath.row]
    cell.carImage.image = UIImage(named: carCategoryImage[indexPath.row])
    cell.carMeters.text = carCategoryMeter[indexPath.row]

    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        print("selected index::\(indexPath.row)")

}
```

Comment: Have you set datasource and delegate for this collectionview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at `ViewController.swift` from the Demo included with ** UPCarouselFlowLayout**, you will see the function `scrollViewDidEndDecelerating`. That is triggered when the scroll stops moving and a cell become the "center" cell.

In that function, the variable `currentPage` is set, and that's where the labels below the collection view are changed.

So, that's *one* place to try what you want to do.

Add the two lines as shown here... when the scroll stops, you create an `IndexPath` and manually call `didSelectItemAt`:

```
func scrollViewDidEndDecelerating(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    let layout = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout as! UPCarouselFlowLayout
    let pageSide = (layout.scrollDirection == .horizontal) ? self.pageSize.width : self.pageSize.height
    let offset = (layout.scrollDirection == .horizontal) ? scrollView.contentOffset.x : scrollView.contentOffset.y
    currentPage = Int(floor((offset - pageSide / 2) / pageSide) + 1)

    // add these two lines      
    let indexPath = IndexPath(item: currentPage, section: 0)
    collectionView(self.collectionView, didSelectItemAt: indexPath)
}
```

You will almost certainly want to add some error checking and additional functionality (like only calling didSelect if the cell actually changed, as opposed to just sliding it a little but remaining on the current cell), but this is a starting point.